Windows 10 unicode symbols after update are gone
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.5011]
Considering that in place upgrade (recovery) is not possible and that I have no system restore points, the problem is that since the last reboot (after a windows update long due, and almost no space left on my system disk at the time of the update)
The system is working fine but soemthing about UNICODE and FONTS is messed up.
I even tried to create a new user and see if the problem was on my own user or system wide.
It is system wide.
Before saying that I need the unicode fonts and the codepage 65001, let me tell you that I have them all right.
What is even more crazy is that the problem affects some programs but not others.
I am pretty sure it was a windows update causing this, and obviously it happened now that Windows 10 Education (my version) is at it's end of life.
In the following examples you will see the same font and size used in:
Notepad
Putty
CONHOST (windows standard console)

the size in the console host is wrong.
Now look:

Unicode is right in 2 programs but not in the console host.
And now the kicker.
This is microsoft edge (and chrome):

Please help me diagnose this.
Obviously I already did SFC /SCANNOW
And dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
Update:
After restoring fonts related registry keys from a backup of my registry of february (too far away to restore it all)
Now unicode works again in chrome/edge:


Why do you believe an in-place upgrade isn’t possible? It’s almost always possible to get an ISO.

@Ramhound I have no space left and I don't want ALL settings restored to default for a stupid error. Also I would like to understand what happened. And why notepad works but  chrome does not? Probably related to DirectWrite or something like that..

What? I have used the in-place upgrade dozens of times and never once lost any settings or personal files.

@Ramhound 1) I did that too dozens of times and I have to re-customize all the os to my liking every time. 2) Your comment has nothing to do with my question. Changing the nature of the question won't answer it. And I want to know what f***ed up.

@Ramhound update: I fixed the problem partially. still the same in conhost but in chrome now they work.

After analyzing everything I found out that, after fixing my registry problems and reinstalling fonts, the problem affects everyone.
Why?
Because CONHOST.EXE in windows 10 does not support font fallback.
Solution:
I now use OpenConsole.exe and everything works :D


Sorry, I don't have enough to post this as a comment.

Could you try changing the font to "Cascadia Code PL" and check?
Unicode character not rendered in Command Prompt · Issue #2576 · cli/cli

Cascadia works bout not other fonts. But fortunately I solved the problem.

Glad to hear it - and to know the solution! BTW, what's your favorite font for musical notes?
